# Intermittent VPN connection in VM

Tags: networking, virtualbox, vpn

I have a Virtualbox VM running Ubuntu inside a Win8 host, using NAT for networking in the VM. I'm connecting to a Cisco AnyConnect VPN client on my host.

The VPN connection works fine on my host machine, but when I try to hit urls that are behind the VPN from within my VPN, it only works a small percentage of the time. For example, doing something like `ping [hostname behind VPN]` might take 10 tries to resolve the hostname.

Is this a common problem? If so, are there steps I can take to resolve it? If not, any idea on what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: No, is not common. Even more, it must work as any -real- machine. Maybe you need a proxy configuration in the VM browsers?

Comment: Can you elaborate a little?